# How to write custom SNMP scripts?

Tags: virtual-machines, snmp, libvirt

I want to send data across SNMP such as VM lv paths, VM disk IO, and VM CPU & memory usage. I've been unable to find proper resources for sending the information I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of virtual machines? Different vendor solutions have different approaches, like https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-56151B75-9A08-4EBC-A460-7A0CA5353C59.html

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the reply, I am using libvirt to run Fedora 34 virtual machines.